# ASP.NET on a linux webserver

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono

Can I host a asp.net application on a linux based webserver?

Do they allow .net framework to be installed on linux?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Mono](http://mono-project.com/ASP.NET) might work for you. It's an open source implementation of .NET that runs on Linux. It requires installation.

You can test your ASP.NET application with [MOMA (Mono Migration Analyzer)](http://mono-project.com/MoMA) first to see if it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page), specifically and it's [ASP.NET implementation](http://mono-project.com/ASP.NET).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the mono project:
http://mono-project.com/Main_Page

It's not 1:1 to the .net framework, but it's as good as you're going to get on linux in terms of .net.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is Mono project - an implementation of .NET framework for Linux OS, I'd suggest you to use Windows server to host your web applications, since Mono doesn't provide all .NET functionality.

Comment: -1? it does make sense to me. It doesn't seem to me that it'd be safe to use mono.
could you explain why you disagree?

Comment: Also I doubt that any web hosting will provide Mono on Linux web server. Why? It's still raw for production usages.

Comment: There is no reason not to use Mono. Mono fully supports ASP.NET and now MVC too. I've been hosting my BlogEngine.NET instance on an Ubuntu server for the last 2 years with no problems.

Shared hosting support is still somewhat lacking, but there are hosts that do it, see www.ubiquityhosting.com for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible, if you have a VPS/VPC server.

In shared hosting server you coudl go for Windows/Plesk, as they have pre-installed ASP.net.
In shared hosting Linux, you may not get root access to install ASP.net, please confirm over the specification from your hosting provider.

If you have a Linux server make sure that you " root access " to install the progamming language.

Comment: You may improve the answer by adding details on which .NET library is available on a Linux VM (e.g. .NET core, etc. see also the Microsoft Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux )